# Angular JS logging data with promises and local storage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage, promise

I want to log actions in my angular app.

If I am not able to post then I want to add the item to another log in local storage so that next time I post I can try and add these items as well.

Once this is done I want to try and post the current items.  I also want to have a (sync) button which runs through the process without going through the action log process. so that the user can try and post all the items they haven't been able to post earlier.

I am thinking of approaching it like this.
on submit

-add item to local storage, then try to post. (so that it posts earlier items first)

on success

-remove item from local storage

on error

-keep item to local storage

I am a fair way down the track of getting this working as shown below, however I am not sure about whether this is the best way to approach this.

At the moment I can post the data on success but not remove the individual item from local storage.

I added in a userService called removeName which I have commented out in my below code, as it currently removes the _nameLog rather than the local storage reference to the item.

But when you run the code in the [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPLxqE) it posts each item every time as I am not removing them on sucess?

How can I remove the local storage item on success without removing the _namelog (as this need to stay in the ng-repeat) or is there a different way I should be approaching this?

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <input type="text" ng-model="updatedname">
       <input type="button" value="Change name" ng-click="changeName(updatedname)"/>
       <br/>
          Hello, {{name}}! 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in nameLog">{{name.value}} - {{name.time}}</li>
    </ul>    
         <input type="button" value="sync" ng-click="syncPosts()"/>
    </div>
    </body>

    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.factory('UserService', ['$window','$http', function($window,$http) {
        var _nameLog = [];
        var userService = {};
        userService.name = "John";
        userService.ChangeName = function (value) {
          userService.name = value;
        };
        userService.logName  = function (value) {
          _nameLog.push ({
            "value":value,
            "time" :Date.now()
          });
        };
        userService.removeName  = function (value) {
           return delete _nameLog[0];
        };
        userService.getNameLog = function(){ 
          return _nameLog; 
        };
        userService.setLS = function(key, value) {
          $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        userService.getLS = function(key, defaultValue) {
          return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        };
        userService.setObject = function(key, value) {
          $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        };
        userService.getObject = function(key) {
          return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
        };
        userService.testPost = function(myVal,myTime) {
          return $http.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {title:myVal,body:myTime,userId: 1});
        };
        return userService;
    }]);

    function MyCtrl($scope, UserService) {
        $scope.name = UserService.name;
        $scope.updatedname="";
        $scope.changeName=function(data){
            $scope.updateServiceName(data);
        }
        $scope.updateServiceName = function(name){
            UserService.ChangeName(name);
            UserService.logName(name);
            $scope.name = UserService.name;
            $scope.nameLog = UserService.getNameLog();
            UserService.setLS('name', JSON.stringify($scope.nameLog));
            getPosts();
        }
        $scope.syncPosts = function(){
            getPosts();
        }
        function testPost(myVal,myTime) {  
            UserService.testPost(myVal,myTime)
              .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
                //UserService.removeName();
              })
              .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error');
            });
        }
        function getPosts(){
            getObj = UserService.getObject('name');
            for (var k in getObj) {
              var myVal = getObj[k].value;
              var myTime = getObj[k].time;
              testPost(myVal,myTime);
              console.log(getObj[k].value);
            }
        } 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: keep in mind this will not work across diff. protocals.. http vs. https (unless of course, you use some sort of iframe shim)

Comment: Umm, I see what you are trying to do, but I am not sure what is the error scenario you are talking about. Why not just use interceptors to requeue you requests. This way you will be able to post back the failed request, for specific scenarios by taking into account what issue you faced.

Comment: i think better approach would be to add it in local store only when error... that way you dont have to keep doing add/remove.. and the some retry functionality using $interval

Comment: @jamesemanon do you have any ideas/best practices here?  I would have thought a lot of API's would be https?

Comment: check out this link: https://github.com/h5bp/lazyweb-requests/issues/106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How can I remove the local storage item on success without removing
>   the _namelog "

You have a few problems with your design:

1) For the local storage key=name the value is an array. In your testPost you don;t know which array item you are posting. If you knew you could retrieve that array from LS splice that element from the array and stringify it back to the LS.

2) It requires too much String to JSON back and forth.

Hence my advice is to follow a key naming scheme like name-0, name-1, name-2 and store each log entry as a separate key. Keep a counter in the LS. Increment this as you add log entry. Then in your testPost you could just delete that key. Pass `k` as a parameter to testPost from the getPosts.

Solution is in [plunkr solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/GGTXtmgkNd7oPBLwgUyr?p=preview)

```
    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
       <input type="text" ng-model="updatedname">
       <input type="button" value="Change name" ng-click="changeName(updatedname)"/>
       <br/>
          Hello, {{name}}! 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in nameLog">{{name.value}} - {{name.time}}</li>
    </ul>    
         <input type="button" value="sync" ng-click="syncPosts()"/>
    </div>
    </body>


    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .factory('UserService', ['$window', '$http',
        function($window, $http) {
          var _nameLog = [];
          var userService = {};
          userService.name = "John";
          userService.ChangeName = function(value) {
            userService.name = value;
          };
          userService.logName = function(value) {
            var logCount = userService.getLS('count', undefined);
            if (angular.isUndefined(logCount)) {
              logCount = -1;//so that this gets incremented to 0

            } 
            var obj = {
              "value": value,
              "time": Date.now()
            };
            logCount++;

            _nameLog.push(obj);
            this.setObject('count',logCount);
            this.setObject('name#'+logCount, obj);

          };
          userService.removeName = function(value) {
            return delete _nameLog[0];
          };
          userService.getNameLog = function() {
            return _nameLog;
          };
          userService.setLS = function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
          },
          userService.getLS = function(key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
          };
          userService.deleteLS = function(key) {
            return $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
          };
          userService.setObject = function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
          };
          userService.getObject = function(key) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
          };
          userService.testPost = function(myVal, myTime) {
            return $http.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
              title: myVal,
              body: myTime,
              userId: 1
            });
          };
          return userService;
        }
      ])
      .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService',
        function($scope, UserService) {
          $scope.name = UserService.name;
          $scope.updatedname = "";
          $scope.changeName = function(data) {
            $scope.updateServiceName(data);
          }
          $scope.updateServiceName = function(name) {
            UserService.ChangeName(name);
            UserService.logName(name);
            $scope.name = UserService.name;
            $scope.nameLog = UserService.getNameLog();
            //$scope.getPosts();
          }
          $scope.syncPosts = function() {
            $scope.getPosts();
          }
          $scope.testPost = function(myVal, myTime, k) {
            UserService.testPost(myVal, myTime)
              .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
                //UserService.removeName();
                UserService.deleteLS('name#'+k);
              })
              .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error');
              });
          }
          $scope.getPosts = function() {
            var logCount = UserService.getLS('count', undefined);
            if (angular.isUndefined(logCount)) {
              return;//there is nothing in log
            }
            for(var k = 0 ; k <= logCount ; k++) {
              var getObj = UserService.getObject('name#'+k);

              var myVal = getObj.value;
              var myTime = getObj.time;
              $scope.testPost(myVal, myTime, k);
              console.log(getObj.value);

            }
          }
        }
      ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if you are using local storage to save names that have not been synced, it is because you want to make sure that if the user doesn't sync before they close their browser (possibly because they don't have an internet connection at the time), the next time they start a session you can try to re-sync those names (hopefully when they have an internet connection). This type of technique is very popular with mobile apps as they come in and out of internet connection all the time.

If this is the case, then it's important to keep in mind that a user could have names waiting to sync from a previous session, and you'll want to make sure that those names get synced with any new names added from the current session.

The easiest solution for this scenario would be to assume that all names in local storage are names that have not been synced (either from the current session or even a previous session).

When the user first starts the session, you would read all names out of local storage to pre-populate the `_namelog` array to show the user all names that still need to be synced.

Every time the user adds a name, you would read the current array of names out of local storage (let's say from the key `namesToPush`), push the newest name to the `namesToPush` array as well as to `_nameLog` array, then `JSON.stringify` the `namesToPush` array back into local storage. You want to always add the name to local storage since you don't know when the user will close the current session.

Then when the user syncs the names, you would read all names from local storage and post them. If the post is successful, you delete `namesToPush` from local storage, otherwise you leave them there to be re-synced later.

The benefits to this approach are that

- You don't have to try to keep track of which names have not been synced in the `_nameLog` array (solves the current problem).
- Using a single array in local storage means only one read/write to local storage on name added and sync, and only one delete (write) on a successful sync

  - If you used a unique key to add names to local storage, you would have to save the first key used for an unsaved batch of names so that you could properly retrieve all names not yet synced in a later session. This could easily lead to [off-by-one errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) since you have to keep track of this index every sync.
  - Although a unique key approach might save you from having to read from local storage on name added, any potential savings are lost on a successful sync since you'll have to delete that many names out of local storage. This could also lead to problems if the user closes the session before all names are deleted from local storage.
- By reading from local storage every post instead of trying to keep a local array of pending names helps to ensure that no name is missed by not being in one or the other (it also helps to eliminate any potential caching problems or posting a name twice due to a bug).

Comment: great explanation! I will see if I can implement your idea.